# Sleep does not work

Tags: linux, sleep

When I choose sleep in the start menu. My PC simply does not go into sleep. I went through the device manager and did all the steps described  [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976877). So far this had no effect.

I've also installed Ubuntu 10.10 but I have the same problem (and in addition I don't know weather the kernel is configured correctly to support sleep) The mainboard is a Gigabyte P55A-UD4.

Comment: What was your operating system before you installed Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: ah didn't mention that.. Primary OS is windows 7; hard to guess, is it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I did have that problem. It works again after marking Windows 7 partition as bootable in the MBR. I don't remember the source or if I figured it myself.

Comment: How can I see which disk is the one the sys boots from? But I guess it's the second (physical!), while win is installed on the first one. So that could be the problem..

Comment: The bootable flag in MBR is not used by Grub. But Windows seams to attach some importance to it.

Comment: In Ubuntu, open `GParted`. Next to your Windows (NTFS) partition, in the "Flags", check that "boot" is present. If not, right-click -> "manage flags" -> check the box "boot"